# What is the use of `!` as return type in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have recently seen a code like this:

```
fn read() -> ! {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn read2() {
}

fn main() {
    read2();
    read();
}
```

I could not find any information about the `!` as return type of `fn read()` anywhere so I don't have any idea what is this and what for.

The only thing I have found seems useless for me:

> Using ! as a return type indicates to the Rust compiler that this function never returns

I don't understand what it does since omitting the type also says that the function returns nothing (the `unit` type actually).

Comment: Returning nothing is not the same as never returning.

Comment: @Lee so it seems you know the answer and you can answer here with a  detailed explanation.

Comment: Well I'll wait for a Rust programmer to answer, but I believe `!` is the empty type, so a function with that return type will never return normally (e.g. it will panic or terminate the program). In contrast `()` is a type with one value so a function with that return type will only be executed for its side-effects.

Comment: @Lee looks like you are exactly right alleging this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unit `()` is not nothing, it *is* a type, with one possible value also written `()`.

Furthermore, when a function returns unit (or "nothing" as you say), it actually returns. The `Never` type `!` specifies that the function *never* returns, *i.e.* quits the program.

This is typically the return type of a `panic` macro:

```
let s = match i {
    1 => "one",
    2 => "two",
    _ => panic!("Error"),
}
```

In this example, note that `!` can "take the role" of all the types. The compiler does not complain that one branch has type `&str` and another has type `!`.

For your information, here is a [little history of the `Never` type](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1216).